# IIS not working after Xampp uninstalled

Tags: php, iis, xampp, port80

I just started working in VS 2012. I started the IIS service successfully, but alongside I wanted to use Xampp also. So, I changed http.conf file's (inside Xampp's Apache folder) servername localhost 80 to servername localhost 8080 and both the servers were working fine.

The problem occurred when I tried to install Xampp with php version 7. I uninstalled old version of Xampp and installed the new version. In my browser the localhost:8080 url shows Xampp dashboard. But I can't see anything in url localhost, which showed me IIS server's dahboard before I had done all this mischief .

Can anyone explain what happened and help me resolve this issue?